# Database design for product catalog site

Tags: database, database-design

I am working on an e-commerce store consisting of products and categories. I have 3 main ways of filtering products: by category, by manufacturer and by gender.

I have the following tables

```
products
- id
- name
- manufacturer_id
- gender_id

categories
- id
- name
- parent_id

products2categories
- id
- product_id
- category_id

manufacturers
- id
- name

gender
- id
- name
```

Using these tables I can list products e.g. find all products where `manufacturer_id = 1, gender = 1, category= 453`.

However I want to have the control of setting images, page titles, meta tags, display order etc for each of these filter combinations. So I have added another table:

```
pages
- id
- category_id
- manufacturer_id
- gender_id
- image
- page_title
- meta_description
- display_order
```

This works, but I now have the task of making sure every single possible combination is in this table. For example when adding a new product, I will need to create all the combinations. Also if I want to add more filters in the future, the table is going to get bigger and bigger. Is there another approach I could use, or is this the only way?

Comment: Why have you created a products2categories table, instead of havin the foreign key of categories in products?

Comment: A separate table for `gender`?

Comment: @ Quassnoi: I hear there is going to be an explosion in the gender category!

Comment: @elvenbyte: not sure about the @op's model, but the products may often belong to several categories.

Comment: The products2categories is so products can be in multiple categories, not just one. Also I think I will lose the gender category, and just store gender_id in products table.

Comment: @Mitch: ten years ago I'd think this is almost as good as my favorite `#define SCREEN_DIMENSIONS 2` but now I'm not so sure!

Answer (score 1):

You could use "default" or "fallback" records which would be selected if there is no exact match, like this:

```
SELECT  p.*, g.*
FROM    products p
JOIN    product2categories pс
ON      pc.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN
        pages gcgm
ON      gcgm.category_id = pc.category_id
        AND gcgm.gender_id = p.gender_id
        AND gcgm.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id
LEFT JOIN
        pages gcg
ON      gcg.category_id = pc.category_id
        AND gcg.gender_id = p.gender_id
        AND gcg.manufacturer_id IS NULL
        AND gcgm.id IS NULL
LEFT JOIN
        pages gc
ON      gc.category_id = pc.category_id
        AND gc.gender_id IS NULL
        AND gc.manufacturer_id IS NULL
        AND gcg.id IS NULL
JOIN    pages g
ON      g.id = COLAESCE(gcgm.id, gcg.id, gc.id)
WHERE   pc.category_id = 453
        AND p.manufacturer_id = 1
        AND p.gender = 1
```

This will first try to select the complete combination of `(gender, manufacturer, collection)` and will fall back first to `(collection, gender)` then to `(collection)` on failure to do so.